# Creating Generic Update Function Using PHP & MySql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm trying to make an Update function that work with any database using PHP & MySQL "PDO" Connection" but it didn't work .. here's the Code

```
<?php
require_once "PDO-Connection.php";
function update ($table, $data, $id, $pdo)
{
    foreach($data as $column => $value)
    {
    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET ({$column}) VALUE (:{$column}) 
    WHERE (ID) = (:{$id});
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(':'.$column => $value));
    }
}
?>
```

Call to this Function

```
update("accounts", array("fname" => "ahmed90"), 1, $pdo);
```

i have (accounts) table & (fname, ID) Fields

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `update("accounts", array("fname" => "ahmed90"), 1, $pdo);` what does $pdo have? where is it defined?

Comment: defined in a seperate PHP Page named "PDO-Connection.php" and called in this page

Comment: You have to fix typos and PHP errors in your code *before* posting your question

Comment: after that you have to learn proper SQL syntax and try if it works without any functions

Comment: after that you have to learn PDO syntax

Answer (score 0):

The SQL code you've written inside UPDATE isn't correct. It should be:

```
foreach($data as $column => $value)
    {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(" update $table set $column = ? where $id = ? ");
    $stmt->execute(array($column, $id);
    }
```

As a side-note, I don't think you really need to create a `function` to update database table rows. Every update you perform in the future might have a set of `preconditions`, or may require `additional computation`, which means you can't use `update` function in every case. Furthermore, if you have more than one column to update, the `$data` array would have multiple entries and also the `foreach` loop runs more than once. This means an SQL update is performed multiple times on the same row which could mean performance degradation.

Comment: +1. Seems to me this answers the question, though I wouldn't include parens in the SQL text that aren't required, i.e. **`= :value`** and **`= :id`**

Comment: You have explained a downvote yourself, in your answer

Comment: Did I say it will? I told the OP where he went wrong, and indicated there's no use of such a function and suggested it would furthermore cause performance degradation. Go through my answer again.

Comment: I am sure with the help of my solution, the OP has learned how to use prepared statements, send arguments and execute them. I am also very sure he learned such a function isn't needed. If it were not for this solution the OP might have not come to know of these things. Your downvoting on this solution might just mislead and discourage the OP from following it. Overall, it seems you have done nothing to help anyone here, which is bad. You should not try to be rude with me.

Comment: Try to be polite and change the way you speak. You are hardly doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an update as :

```
    <?php
include 'connection.php';
function dbupdate($table, $data, $id)
{
    global $link;
    $setColumn= array();


    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $setColumn[] = "{$key} = '{$value}'";

    }

   $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET ".implode(', ', $setColumn)." WHERE ID = '$id'";
    mysqli_query($link,$sql);

}
?>
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

this function works fine:

```
<?php
require_once "PDO-Connection.php";

function update ($table, $data, $id, $pdo)
{
    $setPart = array();
    $bindings = array();

    foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $setPart[] = "{$key} = :{$key}";
        $bindings[":{$key}"] = $value;
    }

    $bindings[":id"] = $id;

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET ".implode(', ', $setPart)." WHERE ID = :id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
}
?>
```

look at ['PHP Sandbox'](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7d18454c912664a3db55752593a719e47bb2340c).

Comment: Check your sql syntax